# Can't display image in slack webhook formatting block

Tags: slack, slack-api

I been using the slack webhook to psot messages in my slack channel. I wanted it to post an image but noticed it won't work for *some* images. I tried using the built in website to display and test and preview and it appears that it is true, some images just odnt work without nay explanation. It seems its not bound to file size since I noticed some files are larger in file size and photo size then mine that faile and even some random ones off google work and some fial without any idea why. What is even mnore funny is

[image]

what is even more funny is, it works as an accessory block but the image block on its own these images fail. I am not sure why or how to fix it or how to report it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the issue, it appears its a bug in slack and they are currently fixing it!

Comment: Did you get any update from Slack since then? The bug seems to be still there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Grab the `permalink_public` and `url_private` from the image file. Extract the secret portion of the `permalink_public` link. This is the last part of the URL, after the last dash, ex.`a0b9cc546f`

Append the following to the `url_private`: pub_secret={secret} (where {secret} is the value that you extracted in in the previous step).

Use the newly generated link as the `image_url` value in a block kit payload.